# Center PopUp in MvvmCross Plugin

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I'm creating a plugin for MvvmCross in which I create a PopUp, but i'm having some trouble centering it in the screen. To center it I'm trying to use the following code:

```
var page = ?; //No idea how to get page
popup.HorizontalOffset = (screen.ActualWidth - ((FrameworkElement)popup.Child).ActualWidth) / 2;
popup.VerticalOffset = (screen.ActualHeight - ((FrameworkElement)popup.Child).ActualHeight) / 2;
```

In Android I was able to get the top activity using:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity
```

In iOS I was able to get the top view using:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow
```

Is there a similar to any of these? Or is there a better way to center the PopUp in the screen?

Thanks

Comment: Could use `Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.application.rootvisual(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code of adding a popup at center of the screen. Put his code on tap event of a button.

```
Popup p = new Popup();
TextBox tb = new TextBox { Text = "This is a test.\r\n Hello Test!" };
p.Child = tb;
p.VerticalOffset = (this.ActualHeight - tb.ActualHeight) / 2;
p.HorizontalOffset = (this.ActualWidth - tb.ActualWidth) / 2;
p.IsOpen = true;
```

Hope, this will work for you.

Comment: I'm trying to create the PopUp in a Plugin not directly in the PhonePage, so i cannot use "this.ActualWidth". The first time I made my sample code, it was exactly like this one. My problem is migrating it to the plugin. That's why i'm having trouble getting the screen. Thanks anyway =)